# Postgres Client - save table sorting

Tags: postgresql, client, sorting

Is there a Postgres client (for Windows) that can save customized sorting when viewing tables? Obviously I could write and save a query for this, but perhaps there's a client that can do this for me. I know MS Access can do this (via ODBC), but I'd prefer a better client.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're looking for.  Maybe pgadmin3?  If not, please explain a bit more.

Comment: Sure, I use pgadmin3, and if I open a table and then sort using certain columns, the sorting is gone when I close the table. I'm looking for a client that can save this information so that the sorting remains when I reopen the table.

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a VIEW? The upside is that it is client independent.

Comment: Yes, that would be an alternative, if no other client offers what I'm looking for.

Comment: I use Navicat which makes sorting real easy, but I don't think it will let you save the current sorts/filters.

Comment: You cannot specify an ordering in a view without using some trickery.

Comment: Can you explain why an ORDER BY would not work?